# Doctrine Skip entities when creating database

Tags: symfony, console, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony2 application, with a bundle that have a couple of entities that isn't part of my main application.

How can I update the schema but exclude some of the entities?

E.G when I run the following command after updating one of my entities

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

then doctrine generates sql for all the entities, which means it creates tables for the entities that I don't need. So how can I tell doctrine to skip those specific entities when generating the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Symfony command doesn't allow that way to exclude any entity.

If you want to differenciate enities from main part to the others, I suggest you define 2 different entity managers, 1 for main entites, 1 other for your annexed entities...

Official doc : [How to work with Multiple Entity Managers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: Thanx, that's exactly what I did and it works great. I did however had to define mappings for all my other entities as well, because auto_mapping doesn't work with multiple entity managers, but that is a small price to pay

Comment: I should have told you as I wrote a post bout this issue : http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/configuration-trick-for-multiple-entity.html

Comment: Using this method, how do you mark a specific Entity as being assigned to one Entity Manager rather than the default?